# vLine API, select div for video call

Tags: api, video, webrtc, vline

I am using the vLine UI widgets for a WebRTC app. (https://vline.com/developer/docs/ui_widgets). 
When the call starts and the video panel is shown it extends to the whole page. Is there any way to restrict to a particular div on the page?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, when you create the vline.Client (https://vline.com/developer/docs/vline.js/vline.Client#create), you can pass the div as one of the vline.Options (https://vline.com/developer/docs/vline.js/vline.Options):

```
vline.Client.create({"serviceId": "your-service-id", "uiVideoPanel": "name-of-div"});
```